# How to emulate network on localhost?

Tags: networking

I'm working on a project that uses robots connected to a server via a router. Because I'm using mulitcast, all robots bind their sockets on the same port (let say 61234). It works fine since each robot has it's own address (192.0.1.10:61234, 192.0.1.11:61234, 192.0.1.12:61234, etc.).

Now I'm using a simulator to make tests, so the robot's code is running on the computer that hosts the server and I'm using localhost to connect robots to the server.

The problem is that every robot has the same address 127.0.0.1:61234 and messages from server are not delivered correctly.

Is it possible to emulate a network on a computer, so that each of my emulated robot can have a different address ?

Comment: It depends! You do not mention the operating system you're working on.

Comment: @DanielB I'm working on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an unused network interface, you can manually assign it multiple IP addresses at once (through "Advanced TCP/IP settings"):

[image]
[image]

If you *don't* have an unused network interface, there are several ways to create one: you could use a VirtualBox "Host-only network" interface for this purpose; you could use a Hyper-V "internal" vSwitch; or you could install a "Microsoft Loopback Adapter". Then assign it a bunch of IP addresses like above.

This doesn't really emulate a whole *network,* as all addresses assigned this way will belong to the same system (like loopback addresses) – but it should work for your purposes.